# InfluxDB Jenkins Pipeline Plugin: Target was null

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, influxdb

I'm using InfluxDB Plugin to send metrics from my Jenkins build to influx. I want to use just the Jenkins Pipeline.

The version of the plugin is 1.10.2.

I add the following code to my Jenkinsfile as indicated in the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/InfluxDB+Plugin):

```
step([$class: 'InfluxDbPublisher',
        customData: null,
        customDataMap: null,
        customPrefix: null,
        target: 'http://ip:port,jenkins-db'])
```

When I execute the build I receive this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Target was null!
    at jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxDbPublisher.perform(InfluxDbPublisher.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:69)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:59)
```

I see the configuration of the target was invalid but I don't understand why. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the another syntax

```
step([$class: 'InfluxDbPublisher',
        customData: null,
        customDataMap: null,
        customPrefix: null,
        target: 'local influxDB'])
```

Comment: Where "target" is in the preference global -> configure